# How to change visited links into unvisited links when something changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, visited

Is there any way to make a visited link back to unvisited without deleteing anything from hystory? I want to do that on a forum, when someone replies in a topic, it has to turn that topic link into unvisited.

I am using this css:

```
a.newold:visited
{color:#999999;}
a.newold:link
{font-weight: bold;}
```

and there is the list of topics:

```
<a class="newold" href="read_topic.php?id=ID">TITLE</a>
```

The thing is: When I click on a topic, it will be automatically updated as visited?

I want something, (if is possible) that when I add a reply INSIDE that topic, its link will be updated as **un**visited

More information about what I am seeking:

Example: The topic name will be: TEST. 
The topic first is unvisited, and it looks like:
**TEST**;

I click on it, I read it, it will look like:
TEST;

Then I add a reply in that topic;

The topic will look **un**visited again: **TEST**;

I think this is as clear as it can be.

If I use some other variable like `$user` seen `topic_id`, it will be bad, because it is a large request, so I wonder if there is something that can be done without database requests.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider editing your question to include some examples of solutions you have tried on your own. Unfortunately, we cannot write your code for you.

Comment: M. Doye has a point. Just an idea: Why not change the link you want to 'unvisit' by adding a dummy argument? That will probably do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can control styles of visited linked with `:visited` pseudo-class. You can defined necessary color settings for visited links and when you need to mark link as replied you can add some CSS class to it, and defined CSS rules like this:

```
a.updated:visited {
    color: #00E;
}
```

Here is a little demo:

```css
a.updated:visited {
    color: #00E;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Visited without class</a>
<a class="updated" href="http://stackoverflow.com">Visited with class</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

When posting to a forum, you could add a query to the link which would cause it to be treat as a new link.

So imagine the link is /topic1 if you answer the question, you could have it attach a query to the link for that user, so it shows back up as a new link, eg. /topic1?=answered

If you needed it to change every time, you would probably need to add a time stamp to this also, so that it is constantly unique every time you answer a question

Comment: Imagine that its about a forum, there will be like idk 100 people? it has to be unique for every person

Comment: then adding a timestamp would do this... The same way you can have CSS files update with a timestamp. The date and time can only ever be the same at that exact point in time... The time has changed since I started writing this comment, and it can never go back to that time. So if your query sting became /topic1?t=2015-03-2211:37:46 then it can never be the same again. It's ugly... But its a solution you can hopefully build upon