# visited link reset in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

Hello guys I'm working on wordpress website and I need option for visited links to reset automatically in unvisited state after one day for my websites users. I cant find any solution so please if anyone made this work on wordpress please let me know. To explain better I need to know is it possible after user clicked links on my website today and changed their state to visited, to make my website reset them automatically into unvisited links every day after random users visited them I need some option like automatic reset of visited links on my website every day for users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change visited links into unvisited links when something changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29193511/how-to-change-visited-links-into-unvisited-links-when-something-changed)

Comment: @AlexandreBeaudet To explain better I need to know is it possible after user clicked links on my website today and changed their state to visited, to make my website reset them automatically into unvisited links every day after random users visited them I need some option like automatic reset of visited links on my website every day for users. no its not duplicate its not even close to my question sorry and also if u voted down for my question sorry if my question was unclear it is my first time asking something here and I'm in need of fast solution.

Comment: Didn't vote the question down, to be honest don't know why it was, it's an interesting question, I'll vote up to cancel out the negative score

Comment: @AlexandreBeaudet ah ty vm seems there is no solution at all if I find anything I'll post here ty again

Answer (score 2):

In short You can't, you can only change visited link color using css

```
a {color:#FF0000;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#00FF00;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */
```

Answer (score 0):

To add up with Bhavesh's answer, visited/unvisited link are **managed in the client's browser**. The only way to truely make a "visited" link "unvisited" is for them to remove the entry in the history.

So the only solutions are :

- Either the client edits his history
- Either you change the link's color using CSS

Sorry that there isn't any good option for your case..